# How do you group by a regex function on presto since you are not allowed to use the alias?

Tags: presto

```
select * from
(select account_id, regexp_extract(....) top_dom from table_name)alias
inner join 
(select acc, from table2_name)alias2 on alias.account_id=alias2.acc group by regexp_extract(....)
```

This throws an error,

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things.

First, you should be able to do 

`select * 
from (select account_id, regexp_extract(....) top_dom 
        from table_name) alias
inner join 
    (select acc
        from table2_name ) alias2 on alias.account_id = alias2.acc 
group by top_dom`

Second, I don't see why you're doing a group by in the first place - you might be causing issues in just doing a `select *` without doing any kind of aggregate with it, such as count. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your code?